# Remove sections of header

Tags: magento2, header

I am creating my custom theme and want to remove some default **blocks** from site. I have tried this code

```
<referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true"/>
```

But it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems pretty well. Check your `referenceBlock` is in `body` node like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

If everything is ok in your code but the problem remains :

- Maybe a cache or compilation problem ? Try a big clean through a `rm var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/di -R` at the root of your magento instance, followed by a `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

Big cleans doesn't fix anything ? Ok, so the problem seems coming from code :

- Check that your layout is actually called by Magento (maybe are you not in the right context). If you are not able to remove a block, can you add a new block for exemple ? If yes, your layout is called and problem is somewhere else ; if no, the problem is here.
- Check that the block you want to remove is actually rendered and with this name. In fact, the `navigation.sections` block exists in default.xml but maybe not in your context (e.g. if a custom theme overrides default.xml theme file).

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi @Nicolas PERNOT  , Thanks for your reply. It was cache problem. Thanks alot :)